# VS2013 gets hung while compiling

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I've a solution with ceratin no: of projects (all of them EXE projects in VC++).
I use VS2013.

This is tied to a version control system (Perforce).

I see that as soon as I start building any of the projects in this particular solution, the VS gets hung.

> I see a text "Not Responding" at the top of the VS window.
>
> Howvever teh compilation happens successfully but it takes a very long
>   time for the compilation due to this hang.

Id the expected compilation duration is "10seconds" it takes 3 mins to compile.

THis problem is seen in both Relaese and debug mode.

A point to note it that the very same projects were building super fast few days back & this issue started few days back.

Evevry other solution and it's projects (except this particular solution projects) are compiling very fast.

Any help is really useful.

Comment: 3:10 is presumably for a clean build. If the build is up to date, rebuilding is not necessary. How much time does it take Visual Studio to discover that yes, all files are in fact up to date?

Comment: Have you tried to compile this problem project on different computer? (to be sure, that it is not a problem of your installation of VS/plugins/viruses/OS/etc)

Comment: When you mention - "This is tied to a version control system (Perforce)." - did you mean that you are using the P4VS plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to reset Visual studio settings trough:

> Tools > Import and Export settings > reset all settings

this will reset all enviroinment settings, then restart visual studio.

edit:
I would also create a new project and copy/paste header and source files from old project to new one, and then compile.

Comment: BUt by resetting like this, wouldn't it remove all the settings done to the "General->C/C++> (header files list), Linker -> INput, options etc.. ?

Comment: yes it will, you can export the settings before resetting, and then importing them back, linker input and header file list can be saved into property sheet... also after resetting you'll be given a chance to set up your enviroinment for specific language. anyway if you don't see any change you can allways restore saved settings. it easier than reinstalling visual studio. did you try to copy files into new project first?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using the P4VS Perforce Plugin with Visual Studio or not. However, there is a possibility that the compile is changing files that are checked into perforce or possibly somehow triggering an update. If you are using P4VS, please try building with it disabled and see if that
builds faster.

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting your computer to see if that works. You may have some memory that was leaked from your program which is making it compile slower than usual. A restart of the computer should free all the memory.

Comment: Yes, I tried restarting the computer but it's the same. I suspect some project/solution related file has some issue. BUt what's surprising is that it was compiling fast as normal till few days back. All of a sudden i see this issue.

Comment: Remove what you've added in the past 3 days and see if it compiles faster

Comment: Actually yes I agreed all these options. And there is no change done in past 3 days. SO I suspect there some VS file got corrupted.

Comment: @codeLover Try to re-install visual studio and uninstall any applications you downloaded in the past 3 days.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with VS, because, using the same VS I'm able to work fine with other solution (*.sln), files. It's only the projects (*.vcproj) of this particular solution (*.sln) that are causing the problem. That is the reason I'm suspecting if some project file or something which VS touches for comiling this has been corrupted.

Comment: @codeLover Hmm that's odd. Well try starting a new project and copy the code over one by one. Or you can remove a file one by one and see if that file is corrupting compilation.

Comment: "Rebooting to free memory leaks" stopped being an answer after Windows ME.